# Zooming in to the number of selected points of Shield UI ASP.NET Chart

Tags: asp.net, shieldui

How can I zoom in to the number of points I have selected on the Shield UI ASP.NET Chart? 
I enable the necessary property:

```
    <Settings EnablePointSelection="true">
    </Settings>
```

but can’t figure out how to invoke zoom in after the selection is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shield UI Asp.NET chart adopts a new and more convenient zooming/panning concept which leaves out the  possibility of selecting multiple adjacent points and zooming in to them.
Instead using the scroll wheel the user can zoom in and out much easier. In addition by holding down the mouse left button the user can move the chart so that the points of interest are in the middle of the plot area. 
One good example can be found here:

http://demos.shieldui.com/aspnet/spline-chart/zoom

In respect to the above information the points selection has nothing to do with the chart’s zooming.